# Javascript: like Facebook posts using facebook javascript sdk?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I'm fairly new in using Facebook javascript SDK and I have no idea what I am doing!

I'm trying to like a facebook post using Facebook javascript SDk in my html page.

My full code this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<div  id="bod" style="width:100%; height:100px; background:#000;"></div>

<script>
$( "#bod" ).click(function() {


FB.api("/10153XXXXXXXXXX/likes", 'post',function(response) {
    if(response === true) {
         alert("done!");
    }
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought this code will like the given post (its ID is 10153XXXXXXXXXX) once i click on the div `#bod` but when I click on the div, nothing happens and I don't even get the `alert();` at all!

could someone please advise on this issue and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you'll need to initialize the FB SDK.

Then, in order to call the API you'll need a valid access token therefore, you'll need to login the user using your App.

I would suggest to double check the docs again:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples

In the second link you'll find an example to login a user and then call the API that I believe will be helpful for you.

I hope it helps.